# Undefined index for get variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a div with the class `.excelDL`. OnClick of the div I am submitting a form using AJAX, without refreshing the page, which seems to work fine.

The problem I am having is I need to detect if `$_GET['excel']` has been set to one after the form is submitted, in my `mail.php` script and I am getting an **undefined index** error. I started getting an undefined index error after I added the submit trigger.

I am new to ajax, I was wondering if someone can help me fix this undefined index problem.

The reason I need a trigger for my form is because all the $_POST values from the form are going to be in the excel file that will be created.

Many thanks in advance

mail.php

```
if($_GET['excel']==1){
    echo '<h1>hello</h1>';
}
```

AJAX

```
           $('.excelDL').click(function(){
                $('#myForm').trigger('submit', function(e){
                    $.post('mail.php?excel=1', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                    //SUCCESS
                    $('.successORfail').html(data);
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(".successORfail").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                                $(".successORfail").empty().show();
                            });
                        }, 4500);
                    }).error(function() {
                        alert("Fatal Error: mail.php not found!");
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });         
            });
```

Comment: Maybe try including the `excel` param as a hidden `input` element?

Answer (score 0):

Don't issue an HTTP POST but use HTTP GET instead. Also don't put the parameter in the request URL but rather in the arguments.

Comment: Or use `$_POST['']` in the php file.

Comment: Changing my $.post call to $.get did not solve the problem. Thanks for the reply tho...